# Merging n number of records into single record in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have n number of records as following:

```
###Date Rank1 Rank2 Rank3 Rank4 Rank5 Rank6 Rank7  
10-01-2015    1    0    0    0    0    0    0   
10-01-2015    0    1    0    0    0    0    0   
10-01-2015    0    0    1    0    0    0    0   
10-01-2015    0    0    0    1    0    0    0   
10-01-2015    0    0    0    0    1    0    0   
10-01-2015    0    0    0    0    0    1    0   
10-01-2015    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

And my desired output is

```
### Date Rank1 Rank2 Rank3 Rank4 Rank5 Rank6 Rank7  
  10-01-2015    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: And what is hthe logic of merging ? doing sum() of rank for a particular day ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `sum()` and `group by`

```
select
Date,
sum(Rank1) as Rank1,
sum(Rank2) as Rank2,
sum(Rank3) as Rank3,
sum(Rank4) as Rank4,
sum(Rank5) as Rank5,
sum(Rank6) as Rank6,
sum(Rank7) as Rank7
from table_name
group by Date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Date, sum(Rank1), sum(Rank2), 
             sum(Rank3), sum(Rank4), 
             sum(Rank5), sum(Rank6), 
             sum(Rank7)

FROM YourTable

GROUP BY Date
```

would work on the above example, but what do you want if there is a 2 in there? After all, ranks usually start at 1, not zero. It would be trivial to select the peak rank for each day by replacing sum() with min().

Comment: Thanks. Yes its works fine for me. In my case i have all 0 other than only one have value.

Comment: Actually i had ranks in between 1 to 50000. i sorted 1 to 100 for Rank1, 101 to 1000 for Rank2, 1001 to 2000 for Rank3,... 10001 to 50000 for Rankn. I generated total number of ranks in all category. After all i got to create one temp table which data as mentioned in the question. In fact it is total no of ranks. @Pepi